# numpy - reason to use 'with' for np.nditer

Tags: numpy

Please explain if tbere is a reason of using `with` for the `nditer` as shown in the NumPy document [numpy.nditer](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html).

It is to understand if there is a necessity that we have to use 'with' when using nditer. In my understanding, 'with' is to make sure a resource (e.g. open file descriptor) gets released. I am not sure what resource is to be released in the code.

```
def iter_add_py(x, y, out=None):
    addop = np.add
    it = np.nditer([x, y, out], [],
                [['readonly'], ['readonly'], ['writeonly','allocate']])
    with it:     # <-----
        for (a, b, c) in it:
            addop(a, b, out=c)
    return it.operands[2]
```

## Update

As pointed out, the [Iterating Over Arrays - Modifying Array Values](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.nditer.html#modifying-array-values) says:

> because the nditer must copy this buffer data back to the original
> array once iteration is finished, you must signal when the iteration
> is ended, by one of two methods. You may either:
>
> - use the nditer as a context manager using the with statement, and the
>   temporary data will be written back when the context is exited.
> - call the iterator’s close method once finished iterating, which will
>   trigger the write-back.

Comment: What is the actual question and what do you expect this code to do? It is a bit unclear (so please edit the question).

Comment: @JérômeRichard, the code itself is from the numpy documentation, and the question is about 'with', if there is a compelling reason that with needs to be used in the code.

Comment: The docs also say: "To get started using this object, see the [introductory guide to array iteration](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.nditer.html#modifying-array-values)." You should read the introductory guide.

Comment: Beware that unless you port your code to `cython` as described at the end of the  intro, you probably won't see performance improvements,